# «Возьмите острый(,) узкий нож» – нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-неоднородные-определения

Нужна ли запятая в данном предложении?

*Возьмите острый(,) узкий нож.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Возьмите **острый узкий** нож.*

Запятая между определениями не нужна, так как они неоднородны, дают характеристику ***ножу*** по степени заточенности и форме.

> 2. Между неоднородными определениями запятая не ставится.
>    <...>
>    Неоднородные определения характеризуют предмет **с разных сторон**, в разных отношениях, т. е. выражают признаки, относящиеся к разным родовым (общим) понятиям: *В углу гостиной стояло **пузатое ореховое** бюро* (Г.) — форма и материал; *Волшебными подводными островами… тихо проходят **белые круглые** облака* (Т.) — цвет и форма.

Источник: [Однородные и неоднородные определения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98) (Розенталь).

**Дополнение** после комментариев oleedd'a (спасибо!)

> 1. Между однородными определениями, не связанными союзами, ставится **запятая**.
>    Согласованные определения являются однородными:
>    <...>
>    **3)** если в условиях контекста, характеризуя предмет с разных сторон, объединяются каким-либо **общим признаком**.

Объединяющим эти определения может стать, например, возможность применения именно такого ножа для каких-то целей. Тогда с помощью запятой и соответствующей интонации мы подчёркиваем то, что нож непременно должен быть и острым, и узким.

Comment: Но её можно поставить: *Возьмите острый и узкий нож.*

Comment: @oleedd Подстановка И не всегда работает. А "изобретать" контекст, в котором признаки сходятся в однородности в таком примере, неблагодарное занятие.

Comment: Она в обратную сторону может не работать, а в эту всегда работает. Контекст легко можно придумать: *Нужно, чтобы нож был узким и острым. Поэтому возьмите острый, узкий нож.* Неблагородное занятие — указывать один вариант, когда возможны оба. А здесь возможность — 50/50.

Comment: @oleedd  Всё правильно! Конечно, первоначально я задумывался об однородности, но вероятнее всего вариант без неё, поэтому не стал усложнять. Ведь если пишут: "Нужно, чтобы нож был узким и острым", то потом уже не повторяют определения, а пишут:  "Поэтому возьмите такой нож".  Спасибо.

Comment: А мне кажется, что 50/50, потому что без запятой не звучит идеально. *то потом уже не повторяют определения* — да, но можно повторить, чтобы акцентировать, просто хотел передать суть, этот смысл можно передать лишь вторым предложением (с соответствующей интонацией), например если говорят о приготовлении. И ещё: могут спрашивать о том, что вероятнее/лучше (но не могу сказать, что без запятой прямо лучше, зависит от замысла автора), а могут в общем (как здесь), то есть надо указать все варианты, можно пропустить разве что бредовые и неудачные.